# What are Apple's policies on font sizes for iPhones, especially 6/6+?

Tags: font, accessibility, iphone

Trying to understand how font sizes in 3rd-party apps will be different on iPhone 6/6+ compared to 5S when all apps get iPhone 6/6+ support:

- What are Apple's guidelines for app developers in terms of font sizes for 6/6+? How are they different compared to earlier iPhones?
- How strictly are those guidelines enforced via app moderation (or any other means)?
- Should all apps effectively demonstrate the same font size for similar UI elements, or they are allowed to decide on the size individually?
- Should DisplayZoom be strictly supported by every app developer?
- Should Dynamic Type be strictly supported by every app developer?